# Does the following lock-free code exhibit a race-condition?

Tags: multithreading, go, lock-free, compare-and-swap

Within the [Kubernetes Go repo on Github.com](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/storage/util.go#L148),

There is a lock-free implementation of a HighWaterMark data-structure.  This code relies on atomic operations to achieve thread-safe code that is free of data races.

```
// HighWaterMark is a thread-safe object for tracking the maximum value seen
// for some quantity.
type HighWaterMark int64

// Update returns true if and only if 'current' is the highest value ever seen.
func (hwm *HighWaterMark) Update(current int64) bool {
    for {
        old := atomic.LoadInt64((*int64)(hwm))
        if current <= old {
            return false
        }
        if atomic.CompareAndSwapInt64((*int64)(hwm), old, current) {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

This code relies on the `atomic.LoadInt64` and `atomic.CompareAndSwapInt64` functions within the standard library to achieve data race free code...which I believe it does but I believe there is another problem of a race condition.

If two competing threads (`goroutines`) are executing such code there exists an edge case where after the `atomic.LoadInt64` occurs in the first thread, the second thread could have swapped out for a higher value. But after the first thread *thinks* the `current` int64 is actually larger than the `old` int64 a swap will happen.  This swap would then effectively lower the stored value due to observing a stale `old` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If another thread got in the middle, the CompareAndSwap would fail and the loop would start over.

Think of CompareAndSwap as

```
if actual == expected { 
   actual = newval
}
```

but done atomically

So this code says:

```
old = hwm // but done in a thread safe atomic read way
if old < current {
   set hwm to current if hwm == old // atomically compare and then set value
}
```

when CAS (CompareAndSwap) fails, it returns false, causing the loop to start over until either:

a) "current" is not bigger than hwm

or

b) It successfully performs Load and then CompareAndSwap without another thread in the middle

Comment: Aha! It just now clicked for me after reading your answer about 5 times.